# WP8 Change the color behind the application bar

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-phone-8

I am writing a WP8 app that overrides the color theme on the phone to always be white. Now before people discredit me for this decision, the app itself is supposed to be a messenger like application and the white background simply makes everything easier to read. In the future I do want to allow people to be able to choose between black or white in case battery life is important but I need to get over this hurdle first.

Currently the problem is that even after overriding the theme colors the color BEHIND the application bar still refuses to change. I'm not talking about the background color of the application bar but the rectangle drawn behind the application bar as it is animated to pop upwards from the bottom of the screen. It is very visible and it is quiet annoying even if it only appears for about a second.

I know there must be a way to do this as applications like Office, Google Mail and Skype all override the color theme and implement the white theme instead and they do not have this same problem.

If anyone could help that would be great!

Comment: I don't have this issue, in my own app. How are you setting your background?

Comment: I'm changing the background color by doing a resource merge to override all default theme colors. I've also tried this.Background = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(Colors.White); but that did not work either.

This problem is only visible when I have the system theme set to be black.

Comment: I have an image as the background for my phoneapplicationpages, maybe that's why it doesn't show the default theme colours for me.

Comment: I have tried that as well. I created a white image and set it as the background but the effect I described still occurs. I'm using a panorama control with application bar opacity set to be 1.0 by the way. This will not happen if my application bar opacity is set to be something lower than 1.0. I can't set the appbar opacity to be lower than 1 though, as I have a message list and it will cover up a list item behind the application bar if the opacity is not set to be 1.

Comment: I've found a hack to my problem although it is still a hack. I can set the opacity of the application bar to be 0.99 (to ensure the color of the bar is very close to what I want) and then simply add a margin to the bottom of the page equal to the height of the application bar.

Comment: Well. That's not really a hack. That's a solution. ;) And yes, that's why I don't have any silly background colour. I just didn't think of it. Sorry. ^^ You should write that as an answer to your own question (if there aren't any duplicates out there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution but it's not a very nice one. If anyone finds a better solution please let me know.

I solved this problem by setting the application bar opacity to be near 1 but not 1 (I set it to 0.99). This will tell windows to not rescale the window (which is the cause of the black background).

I then set the bottom margin of that page to be the height of the application bar.

Here's the code for anyone interested:

```
 private void panoramaMain_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
    Panorama p = (Panorama) sender;
    if(p.SelectedIndex == 1) {
       messageList.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, ApplicationBar.DefaultSize);
       ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
    } else {
       messageList.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
       ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;
    }
 }
```